# Apply a string value to several positions of a cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I am trying to create a string array which will be fed with string values read from a text file this way:

```
labels = textread(file_name, '%s');
```

Basically, for each string in each line of the text file file_name I want to put this string in 10 positions of a final string array, which will be later saved in another text file.

What I do in my code is, for each string in file_name I put this string in 10 positions of a temporary cell array and then concatenate this array with a final array this way:

```
final_vector='';

for i=1:size(labels)
    temp_vector=cell(1,10);
    temp_vector{1:10}=labels{i};
    final_vector=horzcat(final_vector,temp_vector);
end
```

But when I run the code the following error appears:

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.

Error in my_example_code (line 16)
temp_vector{1:10}=labels{i};
```

I am too rookie in cell strings in matlab and I don't really know what is happening. Do you know what is happening or even have a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`deal`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) and put the left hand side in square brackets:

```
labels{1} = 'Hello World!'

temp_vector = cell(10,1)
[temp_vector{1:10}] = deal(labels{1});
```

This works because `deal` can distribute one value to multiple outputs `[a,b,c,...]`. `temp_vector{1:10}` alone creates a [**comma-separated list**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) and putting them into `[]` creates the output array `[temp_vector{1}, temp_vector{2}, ...]` which can then be populated by `deal`.

---

It is happening because you want to distribute **one value** to **10 cells** - but Matlab is expecting that you like to assign **10 values** to **10 cells**. So an alternative approach, maybe more logic, but slower, would be:

```
n = 10;
temp_vector(1:n) = repmat(labels(1),n,1);
```

Comment: If I want to save this string vector as a csv with just one line and separated by commas, can you suggest me how to do that or can I create another question so you can answer?

Comment: yes, ask another question. but it's gonna be something like `fprintf(fid,'%s,',tempvector{:})`

Comment: please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872709/save-a-string-vector-as-csv

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution

```
final_vector='';
for i=1:size(labels)
    temp_vector=cell(1,10);
    temp_vector(:,1:10)=cellstr(labels{i});
    final_vector=horzcat(final_vector,temp_vector);
end
```