# Save a string vector as csv in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, csv

I have the following string array in matlab built the following way:

```
labels=textread(nome_tecnicas_base, '%s');

for i=1:size(labels)
    temp_vector=cell(1,10);
    [temp_vector{1:10}]=deal(labels{i});
    final_vector=horzcat(final_vector,temp_vector);
end
```

I want to save this vector with each string value separated with commas (e.g., csv files) in a text file. I tried in several ways, but when I try to read it with, for example, the textread function i have the following error:

```
a=textread('labels-cpen-R.txt')
Error using dataread
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==>  dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,hierar
```

this is how my file was saved

> dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,dct,hierarch-sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch sift,hierarch-sift,hierarch
>   sift,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,zernike2,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,kpca,sift,sift,sift,sift,sift,sift,sift,sift,sift,sift,surf,surf,surf,surf,surf,surf,surf,surf,surf,surf,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bayesianfusion0,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,bks-fusion,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting4,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,fusionvoting6,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,multiscale_voting,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_rf_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_lvt,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,bks_svr_otsu,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_rf_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt,multiscale_bks_svr_lvt

How can I save this vector and how can I read this file properly?

Comment: If you want to read `csv` files, have you tried `csvread`?

Answer (score 1):

try textscan for reading and fprintf for writing

from the matlab documentation:

```
fileID = fopen('data.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %u8 %f',...
'Delimiter',',','EmptyValue',-Inf);
```

so in your case:

```
textscan(fileID,'%s', 'Delimiter', ',')
```

edit: for writing data to a file, you can use fprintf with a file identifier:

```
 fileID= fopen('data.csv', 'w') ;
 fprintf(fileID, '%s,', data{1,1:end-1}) ;
 fprintf(fileID, '%s\n', data{1,end}) ;
 fclose(fileID)
```